# ¿Cambiar el color del texto seleccionado?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python probando a crear una especie de bloc de notas. Me gustaría cambiar el color en el que se ve el texto seleccionado para que no se vea con el clásico azul de windows; pero me parece que eso no es posible. ¿Podeis confirmarlo? Si existe una manera me gustaría que me ayudaseis. He probado con activeforeground, pero no reconoce ese parámetro.

**El Scrolledtext está justo al final del todo.**

```
from tkinter import scrolledtext
root=Tk()
menu1=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu1)

menuArchivo=Menu(menu1, tearoff=0, background="#E3A16B", activebackground="#785538")
menu1.add_cascade(label="Archivo",menu=menuArchivo)

menuArchivo.add_command(label="Nuevo")
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Abrir")
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar")
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar como")
menuArchivo.add_separator()
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Cerrar")
menuArchivo.add_command(label="Salir")

menuEditar=Menu(menu1,tearoff=0, background="#E3A16B", activebackground="#785538")
menu1.add_cascade(label="Editar",menu=menuEditar)

menuEditar.add_command(label="Deshacer")
menuEditar.add_command(label="Borrar")
menuEditar.add_separator()
menuEditar.add_command(label="Cortar")
menuEditar.add_command(label="Copiar")
menuEditar.add_command(label="Pegar")
menuEditar.add_separator()
menuEditar.add_command(label="Buscar")
menuEditar.add_command(label="Seguir buscando")
menuEditar.add_command(label="Remplazar")
menuEditar.add_separator()
menuEditar.add_command(label="Seleccionar todo")

menuLetra=Menu(menu1,tearoff=0, background="#E3A16B", activebackground="#785538")
menu1.add_cascade(label="Letra",menu=menuLetra)

menuLetra.add_command(label="Resaltar")
menuLetra.add_command(label="Fuente")

myFrame=Frame(root)
myFrame.config()
myFrame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=E+W+N+S)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
myFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
myFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(myFrame, width=40, height=10,bg="#FFDFC4")
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W+N+S)




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la propiedad `selectbackground`, aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Cambia color background del texto seleccionado
text = tk.Text(root, selectbackground="red")
text.pack()

# Texto para el ejemplo
text.insert("1.0", "Texto aleatorio")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Además puedes pasar el parámetro selectforeground al widget Text para cambiar el color en el que se pintan las letras. Por ejemplo asi: `tk.Text(root, selectbackground="red", selectforeground="white")`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!